# SnowFlake - CDC data copy using Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

There is a requirement that I need to copy CDC data from Snowflake without using Stream.

I choose CHANGES clause using by Alter table and able to fetch change data in Snowflake with additional 3 Metadata columns:
But the same way I am using Pipeline reading querying copy activity from Azure Copy activity, but I am unable to copy data.

[image]

[image]

Points:

1. Lookup read all the tables list
2. For Each activity iterates each table and do other operations
3. For each table I'm executing a script which captures time and fetch based on time.
   4, Copy data

Queries I'm using:

```
SET ts1 = (SELECT LASTRUNTIME as Time FROM CDC_TABLE);
SELECT *,$ts1 as Time FROM CDC_TABLE;

 -- change data with all meta data.
SELECT * FROM AGENTS CHANGES(INFORMATION => DEFAULT)  AT (timestamp => $ts1 )  ORDER BY 'AGENT_CODE';

-- change data excluding meta data.
SELECT *  
EXCLUDE (METADATA$ACTION, METADATA$ISUPDATE, METADATA$ROW_ID)
,CASE WHEN METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'TRUE' THEN 'U'
              WHEN METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'FALSE' THEN 'I'
              ELSE 'D'
         END AS CHANGE_OPERATION
FROM (SELECT * FROM AGENTS   CHANGES(INFORMATION => DEFAULT) AT (timestamp => $ts1 ) )
WHERE  METADATA$ACTION != 'DELETE';                                                             

  
  UPDATE CDC_TABLE 
  SET PREVIOUS_RUNTIME = LASTRUNTIME, LASTRUNTIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AGENTS';
```

Above query is not working in Copy data activity, showing below error:
[image]

Please help me on this.
Looking for experts' suggestions.

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question, preferably as editable text. Also, format all code as code (and tables as tables) so that it is readable

Comment: 1) Are you typing the above full script in copy activity source dataset? 2) What is the purpose of script activity inside for-each?

Answer (score 0):

> "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [42000] SQL compilation error:\nsyntax error line 1 at position 157 unexpected ';'.\nsyntax error line 5 at position 11 unexpected ........

This error is because in copy activity source query, query which returns the data to be copied to sink, should be given. You can take the lookup activity/script activity to get the latest run timestamp value and use the output of lookup activity in copy activity source query. The update query should be given in separate script activity and not in the copy activity. The flow of the pipeline inside foreach activity should be as below image.
[image]